# How to install the Java JDK on Raspberry Pi

Tags: software-installation, java

I am an experienced Java programmer who received the Raspberry Pi for Christmas. Unfortunately, it appears that only Python is installed in it. What command do I type at the start command line where I would usually type startx to install the JDK and JRE?

Comment: GCC is also installed in the default distribution so C and C++ are also options.

Comment: A stable release of Oracle's JDK 7 is finally available (see [my answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9585/4395) below). Unlike JDK 8, it's not a beta and it's still fast.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*[Note: Later in 2013 [the Pi Foundation announced](http://www.raspberrypi.org/oracle-java-on-raspberry-pi/) Raspbian now ships with Oracle hard-float.]*

The oracle 8 preview works for me, thus far.  Compiling is slow on the pi, surprise, but the jre seems to run quite fast once it loads. I think bearbin's answer is pretty definitive but if you want a simple way to try oracle:

1. [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-arm-downloads-2187472.html).  You get a .tar.gz file, which is a gzipped tarball.
2. Put the .tar.gz in `/usr/local` and unpack it: `tar -xzf oracle8-blah-blah.tar.gz`.  This will create a directory with everything in it.  You can rename the directory, `mv oracle-jdk-whatever jdk1.8.0`.  Everything in there is self-contained.
3. Put the bin/ directory at *the beginning* of your executable search $PATH.  If there are any other javas installed, that will make this one take precedence: `PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/bin:$PATH`.

That will only work for your current shell.  To make it the default from now on, add this to `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/bin:$PATH
```

Note you must log in again to make `.profile` effective.  **However, if you are using `lightdm`, the default GUI login won't do this, see [here for a solution](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14382/bash-cant-find-rails-in-gui/14389#14389).**

Comment: This helped me carry out [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40284513/5645656) to an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224559/jda-java-bot-on-discord-ava-time-datetimeexception-unable-to-obtain-instant) which someone else (and myself) was experiencing. +1

Answer (score 43):

To install the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

This installs the Java JRE (Java Runtime Environment) which will allow you to run applications written in Java.

To install the JDK run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

This allows you to compile Java applications to bytecode.

If you want the Oracle Java VM, which is a lot faster (optimized for embedded arm CPUs) and is also a developer preview (applications maybe buggy or crash)  until some time into the future. Instead of the above instructions you need to download the file called `Oracle JDK 8 (with JavaFX) for ARM Early Access` on the [Oracle Java 8 download](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) page.

Remember to download the Oracle Java system on your Pi, or you won't be able to install it.

To install the Oracle Java System:

```
sudo tar zxvf jdk-8-ea-b36e-linux-arm-hflt-*.tar.gz -C /opt
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java" 1 
sudo update-alternatives for other commands if needed (e.g. javac).
java -version
```

Then it is all installed.

Another thing, if you have more then one Java runtime installed you have to check which version you use with the command `java -version`. If the output is:

```
java version 1.5.0 gij (GNU libgij)
```

Then you are using another java runtime. You can resolve the issue by running

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and choosing the OpenJDK or Oracle option.

Comment: when running `tar zxvf jdk...` command, two errors (second is repeated): `tar (child): jdk...tar.gz: no such file or directory`          `tar (child): fatal error received. exiting now`

Comment: @imulsion The file may have a slightly different name - type the `ls` command and use the file with a similar name instead.

Comment: what to type after `ls`?

Comment: `tar zxvf []` where [] is the file with a similar name.

Comment: you need sudo in tar zxvf...

Comment: Only because you are copying to /opt. You wouldn't normally need it.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Worked for me on BeagleBone Black, should also work on RPi.

Comment: The "Oracle Java 8 download" link 404's.

Answer (score 8):

Installing Oracle Java 7 JDK (but not JRE) hard-float for RPi is now as stunningly easy as:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk`

([source](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/4920))

I used to go through the old processes that were linked above, but since they easyfied it, now I just do this.

Comment: Better yet, if your Wheezy comes from `2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian` or later ([here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads)), Oracle Java 7 JDK appears to be pre-installed.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo apt-get install java-runtime`

This is OpenJDK 6.

Oracle JDK is not available in armhf flavor, so you have to use a soft-float image to use it.

Comment: Oracle JDK 8 is available in a developer preview. For my case it is working without any problem. http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=26110

Comment: @M Noit it says there are loads of packages that i can install and i need to specify one. what to type in?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle have provided a step by step guide of how to setup Java SE Embedded on a Raspberry Pi device.  They include information on the essential linux setup and some details of optional tweaking/optimisations

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html

Answer (score 0):

Detailed instructions for Java SE Embedded from Oracle are provided [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html).

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, instead of the Early Access JDK 8, you can install the **hardfloat** version of Oracle JDK 7, which has full support from Oracle (unlike the JDK 8).

Oracle's current download page (the same as other Java releases):
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

(No JRE is available, you need to download the full JDK).

Announcement:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=49588

For installation, you can refer to [bearbin's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/4845/4395).