# Has anyone used PyDev in Eclipse on the RasPi?

Tags: python

I'm using PyDev on my Mac and would like my son to be able to use PyDev on the RasPi because it would offer him syntax checking and so on. Has anyone gotten it to work? If so, was it usably responsive?

Comment: I haven't tried eclipse on the pi (good luck), but if you are going to, you might want to do it with the oracle 8 JRE compiled for the pi's hardware, instead of the one that ships with raspbian: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4683/how-to-install-java-jdk-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Eclipse takes on average 300MB of ram. I am not sure you could get it to run on the PI with 512MB. Although this is the minimum requirement, from experience you need at least 1GB. If you do manage to get it to run, it might be from a window manager that uses the graphical accelerator, and with nothing else open.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Does the RasPi have swap on the SD card, or is the card too slow for that?

Answer (score 1):

I was reading [this thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=454) a while ago, and one of the posters had said it works pretty well.