# Javac with Oracle Embedded SE on Raspberry

Tags: java

I'm trying to run Jenkins on my RaspberryPi. Therefore I installed Java (ejre-7u21-fcs-b11-linux-arm-vfp-client_headless-04_apr_2013.gz). But the compiler is missing (so no javac) is there a way to fix this.

I heard that Jenkins runs very slow with the OpenJDK and that is why this is not an option for me. Any suggestions what I might do to get the Java Compiler running on my raspberryPi with a Embedded Java Version from Oracle or just something that runs fast.

Thx

Comment: The Pi most likely has too little RAM to do anything interesting from within Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

*You don't need to use the "embedded SE" version of java on the pi.*  It is not really an embedded platform.  It is a regular PC, albeit a minimal one.

WRT OpenJDK, it is actually a Sun/Oracle product, who of course own the java spec and the mainstream JRE/JDK. OpenJDK started as a fork of Sun java 7, I think primarily so it could have a GPL license.  I.e., OpenJDK is essentially the open source version of Oracle java.  The difference is more in the licensing than the code base.

I haven't seen any tests, but I would imagine the fastest java for the pi is the [Oracle 8 preview](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html) (which is actually a binary compiled from openJDK with hardware float support).  You may also want to look at [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4683/how-to-install-java-jdk-on-raspberry-pi/).

> But the compiler is missing

Make sure you download the JDK (devel kit) not just the JRE (runtime environment).  This may also be a problem with javac not being in your `$PATH`, see my answer to that other question.

Comment: The hard part is porting Hotspot to a new platform.

Comment: Hotspot *is* the JVM.  You don't need to acquire it separately, it's integral to the runtime environment and openJDK.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle released Java 8 (and Java 7) for `ARM`. Use the Link from [this Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-arm-downloads-2187472.html) to get the currently best Java version for your Raspberry Pi.

This should also work:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-jdk
```