# Java JDK 8, use with .jar how to?

Tags: java

I have installed JDK 8 on my Pi but it is still showing JDK 6.. 
Photo for reference: [image: java versions comparison]

How to I change it so that applications use JDK 8 now?
Thank you.

Comment: I'm closing this question, as it does not appear to be specific to the Raspberry Pi within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: This is specific to the distribution you are using.  A good place to ask would be on the Unix sister site.

Comment: If you have not already read **[this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4683/how-to-install-java-jdk-on-raspberry-pi/4929#4929)**, have a look at the part pertaining to `$PATH` (point #3), *and the comment at the end about `lightdm`.*

Answer (score 3):

If 1.8 is what comes up for `java -version` (it does in your screenshot) then that is the one being used by default.

You should not have to change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Like Goldilocks said, if java -version is showing 1.8, that is what is being used.

The only reason I can think that the desktop version is saying 1.6 is because the .desktop file for the JRE or the shortcut on the menu didn't get updated. I can't confirm this or give a way to fix it right now, as my Pi is fried  :'( but everything should be using 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason it is actually using 6 to open the file, you can probably use the "Open with..." entry to specify the command line necessary to run a jar file, e.g. java -jar file.jar if I recall correctly, and specify that as the default run command. (You may need to hunt down the correct location for the Java 1.8 binary though first, not just the environment link.)